# How to match old Instagram user id with the app scoped user id obtained from new Instagram basic display API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I already have an Instagram user's old ID (from the deprecated API https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) and would like to match it with the user-id obtained from the new Instagram basic display API(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/me). Is there a way to match the old user-id to the new user-id?

Note: This is related to the migration of old Instagram API to new Instagram basic display APIs.

Comment: Another problem I have here - in Instagram Basic and in Business they have different Facebook IDs. So, if user don't known about his account type or just to track users across APIs - I can't see any options to match IDs. I can't relay on username - they are subject to change any time by user. I'm talking about ids from `graph.instagram.com/me` and `graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/` methods

Comment: Hey somprabhsharma!
Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @iPeleg No, could not find any solution for this. I used unofficial API `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1` to get old Instagram user-id from username and then mapped it with the new user-id.

Comment: Did you find any solution to link id coming from insta basic app and business app?